# Possible to break on an inline JavaScript being debugged with iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

I plugged my iPhone (6) into the computer (OSX) and fired up Safari 9.
I loaded the website on my iPhone, and safari on the computer is able to connect and show the developer tools just fine. moving the cursor around the developer code shows the blue rectangles on the iphone just fine.

However, some of the code on the website is inside an inline  tags, and I would like to know if it is possible to set a breakpoint and step through the code ?

Comment: Obviously, the best solution (for a variety of reasons) is not to use inline JavaScript.

Comment: Sure, but sometimes that's what you got..